# Why doesn't it take a new value from the list

Tags: python, list

I have problem taking new values from the list velocity. Instead of taking new values for each iteration, it takes the same value. Does anyone have a clue what the problem is?

```
def average_wind(dia):
    wind_list=[]
    velocity=[20,1,1,30,1,1,1,98,1,1,1,1,1]

    for t in range(1,13):
        r=0.2
        area=klass.windpower.calc_area(dia)
        energy=1*klass.windpower.calc_wind_energy(area,velocity[t])
        wind_list.append(energy)

    return (wind_list)
```

Another question, does anyone see anything wrong with how I coded this formula, it is to be similar to the formula Pa = 1/2*0.35*1.2*A*v^3:

```
def calc_wind_energy(self,area,velocity):
    energy=(0.35*1.2*area*(velocity ** 3))*0.5
    return energy
```

Comment: all the values in your velocity list are 1. `velocity[t]` will always return 1 since its the only value contained in the list.  I would also look into using `for t in velocity):` and moving `area=klass.windpower.calc_area(dia)` outside your for loop.

Comment: It produces a list of 12 of the same element, correct?  That's because the only thing that changes in the for loop is `t`, and the only thing that depends on `t` is the element of the `velocity` list to use in the computation -- but it doesn't *really* depend on `t` because all the elements of `velocity` are equal.

Comment: Also using `range(1,X)` is very bad. Iterate over `velocity` itself: `for velocity in velocities:` (and of course rename list)

Comment: Even when I changed the numbers in the list I got the same velocity.. @myaut

Comment: Also, a multiplication by one is not very useful in my opinion, and you don't use the varialble `r`.

Comment: Then is is possible you're not using the second argument in your `calc_wind_energy` function/method correctly/as you expect?

Comment: Also, you should not that indexes start at `0` and not `1` as your range seems to behave. You should use `for t in velocity` as others already stated.

Comment: @saveman71 Thank you, do you know the problem about the formula that I tried to code?

Comment: ```calc_wind_energy``` looks fine.  Cannot reproduce problem.  Try ```for n in velocity: print(n)``` - you can see that that works.

Comment: @wwii Its correct as you say. Do you know if i coded the formula wrongly?

Comment: Your code/equation for ```energy``` looks valid for the Pa formula.

Comment: @wwii please help me, Its really strange since I get the correct value only when I put 1 as a velocity. When I put 50 I get a energy value that isnt correct when I use the formula with my normal calculator

Comment: ```calc_wind_energy```looks correct.

Comment: Also are you using a class or not? One method is calling self as a argument, but the other isn't.  You might want to make average_wind a method in your class and place self.velocity=[20,1,1,30,1,1,1,98,1,1,1,1,1] inside your __int__(self) that way all methods have access to it.